# How to convert an image into binary matrix with matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

this is my code, so the problem is that the file is not in the format that I need, I need a matrix with the values of R, G and B for each pixel of the matrix. I also tried using -mat as the format.

```
%Read the image
im = imread('my_image.png');

%Write to file
save('my_image.txt','-ascii','im')
```

I need a matrix in the following format: three columns, each one representing R, G and B respectively, and MxN rows, being each one a different pixel of the image. The values must be a number between 0 and 255 but written in an 8 bits format

Comment: Loading the image results in an `M x N x 3` 3D matrix which isn't representable by ASCII. What exactly are you hoping the output format would look like? You should show an example

Comment: I need a matrix in the following format: three columns, each one representing R, G and B respectively, and MxN rows, being each one a different pixel of the image. The values must be a number between 0 and 255 but written in an 8 bits format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) to write matrix as ASCII delimited file.

```
%Create a matrix of size 4x5x3 with random integers between 1 and 10
>> a = randi([1 10], 4,5,3)

a(:,:,1) =

 5     6     1     9     7
 2     5     1     9     6
10     1     6     8    10
 8     7     1     2     7


a(:,:,2) =

 9     1     9     6     3
 5     2     9     5     5
 5     2     1     7     1
 9     4     4     7    10


a(:,:,3) =

 2     5     1     6     4
 2     4     8    10     8
 4    10     3     5     7
 2    10     5    10     6


%Write the matrix to file
>> dlmwrite('f1.txt', a);
```

Contents of file `f1.txt`:

```
5,6,1,9,7,9,1,9,6,3,2,5,1,6,4
2,5,1,9,6,5,2,9,5,5,2,4,8,10,8
10,1,6,8,10,5,2,1,7,1,4,10,3,5,7
8,7,1,2,7,9,4,4,7,10,2,10,5,10,6
```

If you want a different ordering, for e.g., group R, G and B separately, you could do:

```
>> dlmwrite('f2.txt', a(:,:,1))
>> dlmwrite('f2.txt', a(:,:,2),'-append')
>> dlmwrite('f2.txt', a(:,:,3),'-append')
```

Contents of file `f2.txt`:

```
5,6,1,9,7
2,5,1,9,6
10,1,6,8,10
8,7,1,2,7
9,1,9,6,3
5,2,9,5,5
5,2,1,7,1
9,4,4,7,10
2,5,1,6,4
2,4,8,10,8
4,10,3,5,7
2,10,5,10,6
```

#### Edit 1

As *Suever* rightly said, you cannot store a 3D matrix in an ASCII file unless you flatten it to 2D.

```
>> a1 = reshape(a(:,:,1), [],1)
>> a2 = reshape(a(:,:,2), [],1)
>> a3 = reshape(a(:,:,3), [],1)
>> a4 = horzcat(a1, a2, a3)

a4 =

 5     9     2
 2     5     2
10     5     4
 8     9     2
 6     1     5
 5     2     4
 1     2    10
 7     4    10
 1     9     1
 1     9     8
 6     1     3
 1     4     5
 9     6     6
 9     5    10
 8     7     5
 2     7    10
 7     3     4
 6     5     8
10     1     7
 7    10     6

>> dlmwrite('f3.txt', a4)
```

Contents of file `f3.txt`:

```
5,9,2
2,5,2
10,5,4
8,9,2
6,1,5
5,2,4
1,2,10
7,4,10
1,9,1
1,9,8
6,1,3
1,4,5
9,6,6
9,5,10
8,7,5
2,7,10
7,3,4
6,5,8
10,1,7
7,10,6
```

#### Edit 2

To write the numbers in 8-bit format:

```
%Convert decimal to 8-bit binary
>> b1 = dec2bin(a1, 8);
>> b2 = dec2bin(a2, 8);
>> b3 = dec2bin(a3, 8);

%Create array of blank characters to serve as delimiter
>> delim = blanks(size(b1,1))';

%Horizontal concatenation
>> b4 = horzcat(b1, delim, b2, delim, b3)

b4 =

00000101 00001001 00000010
00000010 00000101 00000010
00001010 00000101 00000100
00001000 00001001 00000010
00000110 00000001 00000101
00000101 00000010 00000100
00000001 00000010 00001010
00000111 00000100 00001010
00000001 00001001 00000001
00000001 00001001 00001000
00000110 00000001 00000011
00000001 00000100 00000101
00001001 00000110 00000110
00001001 00000101 00001010
00001000 00000111 00000101
00000010 00000111 00001010
00000111 00000011 00000100
00000110 00000101 00001000
00001010 00000001 00000111
00000111 00001010 00000110

%Write to file without the default ',' delimiter
>> dlmwrite('f4.txt', b4, '')
```

Contents of `f4.txt`:

```
00000101 00001001 00000010
00000010 00000101 00000010
00001010 00000101 00000100
00001000 00001001 00000010
00000110 00000001 00000101
00000101 00000010 00000100
00000001 00000010 00001010
00000111 00000100 00001010
00000001 00001001 00000001
00000001 00001001 00001000
00000110 00000001 00000011
00000001 00000100 00000101
00001001 00000110 00000110
00001001 00000101 00001010
00001000 00000111 00000101
00000010 00000111 00001010
00000111 00000011 00000100
00000110 00000101 00001000
00001010 00000001 00000111
00000111 00001010 00000110
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I actuallly used another method I just found yesterday, but I really appreciate your help !

Comment: No problem :)care to post your method as an answer?